# Discovering the Cause of tcp rcvpruned?

Tags: linux, tcp

I get a few rcv pruned packets on my load balancers a day and I would like to know what the cause is:

[image]

However, based on my tcp_mem vs tcp_mem usage I don't understand why some packets are being pruned:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
6178080 8237440 12356160
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` ? You might consider increasing the initial buffer size and see if that prevents buffer overruns (i.e pruning).

Comment: Is this really causing an issue for you or were you just trying to make sense of the graph?

Comment: @JoelDavis: It is our load balancer, so it could mean a few people are getting a slower page load when loading these sites a day, so super critical! (Okay, it probably isn't a big deal, but "the more you know"

Comment: @JoelDavis: And tcp_rmem is `183936 245248 367872`, so I should still be okay unless there are some spikes between my polling of tcp_mem (which is every 15 seconds)

Comment: You may try playing around with [the different TCP congestion algorithms](http://linuxgazette.net/135/pfeiffer.html) linux has available. It might just be an issue with congestion control.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the pruned queue?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP `RcvPruned` MIB is incremented just before the kernel leaves the `tcp_prune_queue()` function, resulting in dropping of packets.

Prior to this, the kernel will have tries to collapse data in socket buffers (squeeze data together and discard overheads). Data will first be pruned from the out-of-order queue, then from the regular in-order queue.

This means your sockets are facing memory pressure, likely your socket buffers are not big enough.

You said above:

> ```
> net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 183936 245248 367872
> ```

The maximum is nowhere near big enough. Increase it to 10x that value to give the kernel room to increase socket memory as it wants to. Increase `net.core.rmem_max` as well, as that is used in TCP window accounting.

I'm not sure how you've calculated your buffer sizes, but if you're load balancing lots of small-packet traffic (like HTTP requests) then most of your buffer usage will be overhead.

Depending on which kernel you're running, there is different accounting for this. The "old" method makes some inaccurate assumptions but turns out to be quite forgiving, the "new" method accounts accurately and requires buffers to be sized a bit larger than previous.

The patch set which changes this focuses around the calculation of `skb->truesize` and IIRC was applied sometime between kernel 3.0 and 3.10.

You also will want to check the value of `net.ipv4.tcp_mem` and make sure you're not restricting the amount of total memory TCP is allowed to use. This tunable is measured in *pages*, not bytes. Personally I just make all values so big they'll never be hit. Buy more memory as required.